# Has grub submenu indexing recently changed in 18.04.2?

Tags: grub2, 18.04, kernel

After updating the kernel, I always keep just one previous version. I now have 4.14.0-46 ( which was the default) and 4.15.0-45. Investigating whether the new kernel was responsible for the plymouthd system error/crash, I wanted to set -15 as the default boot kernel.

Changing /etc/default/grub entry  from `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>3"` had previously brought up the normal -45 mode. Now it starts up the recovery version. If I change the entry to "1>2", it starts in 4.15.0-45 generic normal mode.

I know that unlike the other grub indexing the submenu's menuentry numbering started at 1. Now it appears to start at 0. Is this correct and a recent change?

Comment: You can always run `apt changelog grub2` and see if there is a change for that in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3 answers...**

---

Rather than having to edit `/etc/default/grub` every time GRUB changes, this way will remember the last OS/version that you booted, for the future boots, until you decide to change it, so edit your `/etc/default/grub` to include these...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    # edit existing line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # add this line
```

then do `sudo update-grub`.

---

If you wish to remain editing `/etc/default/grub` the way that you have been doing it, instead of using positional numbers, use the description text instead... (*use the exact text shown in the GRUB menus*)...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced Opti...>Ubuntu 14..."
```

then do `sudo update-grub`.

---

<strike>To possibly fix your Plymouth crashes, also edit `/etc/default/grub` and change...</strike>

**Note**: if you've changed your splash screen, or added a GRUB background, these can also cause plymouth problems.

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to...

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

then do `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 doesn't fix the plymouth crash

Comment: @NickT although the question was regarding GRUB, I also took a quick shot at fixing your plymouth problem, but there really wasn't enough information about it. Maybe you can accept my answer here, and start a new question for the plymouth problem, and we can take a closer look, ok?

Comment: @NickT have you added a GRUB background image, or changed the splash screen? These can cause plymouth problems.

Comment: re: plymouth crash - Nothing has changed other than the kernel version. I have proved that 4.15.0-46 crashes, 4.15.0-45 doesn't.

Comment: @NickT the -46 kernel **might** be the cause, but so **might** `/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic`. Do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-46-generic`. Then reboot to -46. Report back.